# how to remove feature from store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, store

I have an app store for my main module (global).

But, I have another module, which is lazy, and contains a featured store. Let's name it `users` module (with `/users` route).

1. When I access the application on homepage (app module), the app store will be loaded.
2. When I navigate to `/users` route, users module will be loaded, togheter with users store (featured store)

   - in this moment, my store is computed by `/app-store` and `/users-store`.
3. I navigate outside users and I want to remove /users-store from my state.

I tried in `ngOnDestroy` of my principal users component to reinitialize the user state (because I don't know how to remove it), but the action is not fired.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.store.dispatch(fromFeature.resetStoreAction());
}
```

I need it, because the modules are accesible by roles, and I don't want to keep in memory `users-store` useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove state leafs with `removeReducer`, it could be that you'll have to re-add the feature manually if the user navigates again to that page tho when you do this.
See my blog post [An experiment, using the global NgRx Store as a local store](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/an-experiment-using-the-global-ngrx-store-as-a-local-store) for more info.

Personally, I don't see why this state needs to be removed, if the state is bound to the component's lifecycle - I think a NgRx Component Store would fit your needs better. https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store

```
 constructor(
    private reducers: ReducerManager,
  ) {
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.reducers.removeReducer('feature-name');
}
```